# Is the pitch data correct in this pdf file intended for learners?

Tags: verbs, pronunciation, dialects, pitch-accent

(*If the question is inappropriate here, please direct me to an appropriate site or forum*)

In an effort to simplify the acquisition of pitch in L2 learners (ie. myself), I created a pdf document that groups verb endings and morphemes into more manageable groups: [Verb Pitch Table](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/353241/verb%20pitch.pdf).

However, reliable data is difficult to establish.

**Can anyone confirm that the data is accurate for Standard or Tokyo Japanese?**

I asked 2 Japanese speakers (1 quickly, 1 in detail) and it seems okay. The only problem is that some of the data conflicts with what I found in my NHK Accent dictionary. For instance, after accentless verbs, でしょう、だろう、らしい are said to have pitch on the antepenultimate mora, but this was thought to be odd by the speakers I asked；とも is said to be HL but the one speaker thought it should be H]LL (downfall occurs before). My goal is to create a quick and easy reference for anyone wanting to sound like the average speaker of the Greater Tokyo Area.

I realize the question is complex, but I hope to provide an efficient method to help learner predict pitch in all verbs with the help of a simple all-encompassing tool.

Comment: It took me several (not a few) seconds to figure out what you mean by "pitch are expressed in bold" in the document. I think you mean "the accent nucleus is expressed in bold". I suspect a beginner will mistakenly take it that the bold expresses high pitch and normal weight low pitch.

Comment: You don't have an explanation for what the vertical line means. If you mean fall of pitch, then it is strange that you do that for falling pitch, which is clear given the accent nuclues, and nevertheless not do it for raising, which is less obvious.

Comment: Right, the line is redundant in a sense. I assumed it would make it clearer. And I shouldn't have it in the "No effect" section at first. There are a few logistical issues to fix.

Comment: sawa, how about "Bold indicates accented mora"? There either is a single accented mora or there isn't, and the table would be preceded by basic pitch information that would teach the learner to derive the height of all other morae.

Comment: @alexandrec: as it is, your question is too localised for JLU: it involves an external document which will likely disappear in the near future, leaving a question that is neither intelligible nor useful for any future visitor. Please remedy that by embedding part of it in your question or in any other way that makes your question suitable for this site.

Comment: I could take the data from the pdf page and add it to the question, but it would be quite long...

Comment: @alexandrec I think you should do what you wrote above ("Bold indicates ..."). And Dave is right. You should put materials here. Both Dave and my comments point to the fact that the way you asked the question is very reader unfriendly (It shows a lack of your errort in asking a question). That's probably one reason you haven't got any answer yet.

Comment: I would gladly have taken the time to ask the question properly but there must be over 60 verb forms on the pdf, so I think it would be impractical to post them all here. I will try to consider a different way to ask.

Comment: I understand the motivation behind the "-3", "-2"-style notation, but it is a bit oversimplified and might be misleading in some cases. For example, "accented + て" is "-3", which is correct for 食べて but incorrect for 射て (-2) and 帰って (-4). Also it tends to obscure larger patterns, like behavior before ない-conjugations like なくて, なかった etc, where the length of the final morpheme is not really relevant to the location of the pitch nucleus.

Comment: Incidentally, reliable data is not actually difficult to establish! Go out and buy the NHK's pronunciation dictionary (発音アクセント辞典) -- they have all this stuff tabulated and explained, ready to go.

Comment: @Matt -- I don't know about "ready to go". I wanted to group the info in a format that's easier to remember. 射て is easy to account for, but I didn't expect 帰って(-4)! I'll be darned!

Comment: @Matt NHK's standard is highly prescriptive, and hence, unrealistic. They speak a dialect only spoken by announcers. One example that annoys me is that they pronounce "十回" as "じっかい", but in the real world but NHK (or other TVs), normal people will pronounce it as "じゅっかい".

Comment: @sawa True, it's prescriptive rather than descriptive and has a few odd quirks, but I think for the purposes of accent (particularly how it changes upon conjugation/combination) it is fairly sound. Maybe less so for gairaigo. (Actually, I myself prefer Shinmeikai's pronunciation dictionary, but I always cross-reference both when I'm looking something up.)

Comment: @alexandrec I definitely recommend checking out either NHK's or Shinmeikai's approach to the issue -- it's not the dictionary part I'm recommending so much as the 解説 at the front/back, which includes summary tables and rules quite like what you seem to be doing here.